# Laravel merge collections and sort by value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am looking to merge two Laravel collections and sort them by a field name. Here is what I did to get two collections.

```
$bills = BillLine::where('item_id',$this->item_id)
    ->join('bills', 'bill_lines.bill_id', '=', 'bills.id')
    ->select('bill_lines.confirmed_on','bill_lines.qty','bills.serial')
    ->get();

$invoices = InvoiceLine::where('item_id',$this->item_id)
    ->join('invoices', 'invoice_lines.invoice_id', '=', 'invoices.id')
    ->select('invoice_lines.confirmed_on','invoice_lines.qty','invoices.serial')
    ->get();
```

Now I want them to be merged and sorted by the confirmed_on field. This way I can loop them in the blade table. I tried and couldn't. Then I tried converting these two to arrays and merge them which is possible using `array_merge()` but sorting becomes the issue.

1. how to merge two collections
2. once merged in can use sortBy on collection to get it sorted.

Comment: try $bills->mergeRecursive($invoices)->sortBy('columName');

Answer (score 3):

**You can merge collections using the [merge()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-merge) method.**

Be aware though, that  if a `string` key of the merged collection matches a `string` key in the original collection, it will override the entry in the original collection. To prevent that from happening, I think you can call [values()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-values) method on both collections before merging, so the keys are reset to consecutive integers.

After the collections are merged, you can simply call [sortBy method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby).

**Example:**

```
$bills->merge($invoices)
    ->sortBy('confirmed_on');
```